# comparing the value that it should be defined one

Tags: java

I have a pojo in which one field is defined  as

```
private Long abcId;
```

and now in another java class I am fetching its value which is stored in an object S and I am fetching  it like this as shown below as I need to test that it value should be 565869, so I am doing that    as shown below please let me know it is correct approach

```
S.getabcId().equals("465781052"))
```

Comment: Why don't you override the `equals()` method in the pojo? Also, try `Long.toString()` to convert the `Long` to `String`. or `Long.valueOf()` to convert the `String` to `Long` (mind the possible exception).

Comment: @Aquillo  I am checking this conditions in some other class with if condition

Comment: @Aquillo please let me know is my approach is correct.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have written an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Long's `equals()` method checks if the parameter passed is `Long` or not. Hence for a `String` argument `equals()` would always return `false`. Do the comparison as

```
s.getAbcId().equals(Long.valueOf("105226610"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like:

```
if (S.getabcID().longValue() == 565869L) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Edit: added .longValue()

Comment: Yes but the value is of long type in pojo , Please advise

Comment: The L signifies that the number is a long

Comment: @TuntunDfdd Value in pojo is of type Long (wrapper) not long (primitive). There's a difference.

Comment: then why don't you just do if (S.getabcID().longValue() == 565869L) ?